# set a distance for a onscroll div to top

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three div, a menu and three links, when I click on each links; page scroll to related div, and top of that div riches to top of page.
how can I set a 40px distance between top of screen and top of that div?
here is my codes:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #menu{width:100%;height:40px;background:yellow;position:fixed}
        #menu ul li{display:inline;padding:10px}
        #top, #middle, #bottom{height:800px;border-top:1px solid}
    </style>
    <script>
        window.smoothScroll = function(target) {
            var scrollContainer = target;
            do { //find scroll container
                scrollContainer = scrollContainer.parentNode;
                if (!scrollContainer) return;
                scrollContainer.scrollTop += 10;
            } while (scrollContainer.scrollTop == 0);

            var targetY = 0;
            do { //find the top of target relatively to the container
                if (target == scrollContainer) break;
                targetY += target.offsetTop;
            } while (target = target.offsetParent);

            scroll = function(c, a, b, i) {
                i++; if (i > 30) return;
                c.scrollTop = a + (b - a) / 30 * i;
                setTimeout(function(){ scroll(c, a, b, i); }, 20);
            }
            // start scrolling
            scroll(scrollContainer, scrollContainer.scrollTop, targetY, 0);
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a onclick="smoothScroll(document.getElementById('top'))">Top</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a onclick="smoothScroll(document.getElementById('middle'))">Middle</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a onclick="smoothScroll(document.getElementById('bottom'))">Bottom</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="top"><h1>Top</h1></div>
    <div id="middle"><h1>Middle</h1></div>
    <div id="bottom"><h1>Bottom</h1></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't want h1 hide before menu.

Comment: ahhh  ... subtract 40? Not complicated

Comment: what do you mean? here's demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sabeti05/f18d0fj3/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to measure the Topbar height when calculating the scroll targetY.

```
// get topbar height to offset the scroll taget coords
var topbarHeight = document.getElementById("menu").offsetHeight;

// apply scroll offset
targetY -= topbarHeight;
```

Live demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/f18d0fj3/3/

Comment: @MojtabaSabeti Read the code before copy-paste so you can understand what are you doing. You have to paste it right before calling scroll() on the last line

Comment: first I read the code and try to understand, but couldn't. thanks, your updated jsfiddle helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add some padding to your div's :

```
#top, #middle, #bottom{height:500px;border-top:1px solid; padding-top: 30px}
```